# How to send selected parameters to SignalR to receive the latest value from Windows Table Storage

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr, azure-table-storage

I have a azure table storage which contains data for some 22 *parameters* (say P1,P2...) holding data for

1. `value`
2. `quality`
3. `time_received`

`PartitionKey` will hold the name of the parameter and `RowKey` will hold the time_received

At the Back-end the table receives its latest value for each *parameter* from its configured device.

At the Front-end SignalR is employed to display the latest data of a *parameter* 
This is the code to start SignalR

```
 $.connection.hub.start();
 signalHub.client.SendSignalData = function (signalData) {

        $("#newValue").text(signalData);
    };
```

In my SignalR Hub

```
public class SignalHub : Hub
    {

        public SignalHub()
        {
            // here, am getting the latest data from Azure Table Storage for first parameter P1
            GetAllClients().All.SendSignalData(pt_1model.Value);// and sending that data to UI 

        }
```

**My Requirement**

The 22 *parameters* are listed as checkboxes in the UI.
Now I need to allow the user to select the *parameters*  they'd need to display in the UI.

As per their selection of *parameters* the system should fetch the latest values from storage table  for all  selected  *parameters'*  .

**My Query**

1. How will I be able to send the selected checkboxes value to the SignalR Hub such that I can get the latest data of all the selected parameter from the storage table?
2. How will be able to send back the latest values of slected parameters back to UI?

Comment: Do you achieve the requirements? I have shared some code for your reference, are you able to communicate with Hub server?

Comment: Thanks Fred Han. Yes I am using a method to send the selected parameter list. I was checking if we can have a overloaded constructor to include the parameters.

Regarding sending parameters I am collecting the checked items in a variable and sending the list to return back with required info.

And I get different exposure say paraobj... from your code below. Thanks.

Comment: ``paraobj`` is a custom class/type that defined by myself and deserialize the JSON to this type.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check “[How to define methods in the Hub class that clients can call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-define-methods-in-the-hub-class-that-clients-can-call)” and “[How to call client methods from the Hub class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-call-client-methods-from-the-hub-class)” sections to define your Hub methods and client functions.

Secondly, you could also refer to the following sample code to define your client function and Hub method to push the latest data to clients.

*Client function:*

```
signalHub.client.SendSignalData = function (latestdata) {
    //extract data from returned "latestdata" object
    //use jquery selectors to find the elements and update UI
}
```

*Hub method:*

```
public void GetTheLatestData(string pars)
{
    paraobj json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<paraobj>(pars);

    //query entities from table 
    //and call client function SendSignalData to update UI with the latest data

    Clients.All.SendSignalData({the latest data});
}
```

*Client call hub method with parameters:*

```
var pars = { "P1": "val1", "P2": "val2"...};
//in your project, please dynamically generate pars with selected checkboxes values

signalHub.server.getTheLatestData(JSON.stringify(pars));
```